# Popover not closing when clicking outside its focus area

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Bootstrap Vue with Vue.js and am experiencing a problem where I'm iterating over some items and displaying them to the user.

The issue is, when a user clicks on one of the popovers, every popover that was opened gets closed (as I desire), but when the user clicks outside the focus area of the targeted (opened) popover, it doesn't close anymore.

It looks like the opening animation runs every time the user clicks on the targeted popover.

Here is the code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row" v-for="(n, i) in 5" :key="n">
      <div :id="'popover' + visitor.id + '-' + i" @click="$root.$emit('bv::hide::popover')">
        <div class="card">
          <b-popover :target="'popover' + visitor.id + '-' + i">
            <template slot="title">
              Edit image
              <button
                class="close-popover"
                @click="$root.$emit('bv::hide::popover', 'popover' + visitor.id + '-' + i)"
              >X</button>
            </template>
          </b-popover>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You can set `triggers="click blur"` on the popover. This will close it when the user clicks outside of the popover or on the target.

You can check more [HERE](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/popover#dismiss-on-next-click-self-dismissing).

Comment: In addition to @Vedran 's comment, mention that you don't necessarily need a button to accomplish this. You can use attribute tabindex="0" in the triggerable element to make it focusable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function in created

```
created(){
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].addEventListener('click', e => {
      this.$root.$emit('bv::hide::popover')
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this Jquery to your code and it will work, probably.

```
 $('body').on('click', function (e) {
        $('[target=popover]').each(function () {
            if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $(this).popover('hide');
            }
        });
    });
```

Also you can try this:

You can add this to your code and try.

```
 <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
```

Also add this jquery:

```
 $('.close').click(function() {
       $(".class").fadeOut(300);
    });
```

Comment: I'm using Vue.js, so jQuery is not an ideal solution. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I am also working on the same stuff and this gets my work done

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is the vue directive [v-click-outside](https://github.com/ndelvalle/v-click-outside).

Basically, you just install it: `npm install --save v-click-outside`

And use:

```
<template>
  <div v-click-outside="onClickOutside"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this directive does not work.
It seems like Vue.js doesn't recognize it.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

add the attribute **tabindex='0'** to the click element

```html
<span id="popover" tabindex='0'>test</span>
```

add set the triggers to 'click blur'

```html
<b-popover
   target="popover"
   title="Prop Examples"
   triggers="click blur"
   content="Embedding content using properties is easy"
/>
```